# Apache Archiva 1.4-M4 - Deployment Issue

Tags: archiva

Im in the process of evaluating the new interface of Apache Archiva. The user interface is really good and I was able to configure most of the settings.

However, when I try to deploy the artifact through eclipse Im getting the below error.

Error code 405, HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL

I donot get this when I use the Apache Archiva 1.3.6.

Any idea?

Comment: I hope there is a bug in the 1.4.M4.                                          This is a only issue having according to my need. All other features are working as expected :)

Comment: Could you file this at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM ?

Comment: Hi, Let me know the login details for JIRA so then I can log the issue.

Comment: You can sign up at http://xircles.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup the new Archiva version 2.0.0. Apparently this issue has been fixed with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your repository URL is incorrect.  See [GitHub issue 4](https://github.com/xetus-oss/docker-archiva/issues/4).